# gRPC client side reconnection logic causing duplicate streams to be opened server side

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I have a gRPC client that uses two bidi streams. For reasons unknown at the present, when we send a keepAlive ping every hour, onError with a `statusRuntimeException` are called on both streams.

To handle the reconnection, I've implemented the following retry mechanism, in java pseudocode. I will clarify anything as necessary in the comments.

The mechanism looks like so:

```
onError() {
    retrySyncStream();
}


void retrySyncStream() {
    // capture the current StreamObserver
    previousStream = this.StreamObserver;

    // open a new stream
    streamObserver = bidiStub.startStream(responseObserver);

    waitForChannelReady(); // <-- simplified version, we use the gRPC notification listener 

    previousStream.onCompleted(); // <-- called on notify of channel READY

}
```

Although we attempt to close the old stream, server side we see 2 connections open on 2 HA nodes. I don't have control over anything server side, I just need to handle reconnection logic on the client.

First things, is this common practice to ditch the old StreamObserver after getting a StatusRuntimeException? The reason I am doing this is because we have a mock server spring boot application that we use to test our client against. When I do a force shutdown (Ctl-c) the spring boot server app, and start it back up again, the client can't use the original StreamObserver, it has to create a new one by calling the gRPC bidi stream API call.

From what I've read online, people say not to ditch the managed channel, but how about stream observers, and making sure that multiple streams aren't being opened by mistake?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the StreamObserver gets an error, the RPC is dead. It is appropriate to ditch it.

When you re-create the stream, consider what would happen if the server is having trouble. Generally you'd have exponential backoff in place somewhere. For bidi streaming cases, several cases in gRPC tend to reset the backoff if the client received a response from the server.

Since both streams die together, it sounds like the TCP connection was dead. Unfortunately, in TCP you have to send on the connection to learn it is dead. When the client learns the connection is dead, it learns that because it *can't* send to the HA proxy using that connection. That means HA has to separately discover the connection is dead. Server-side keepalive could help with this, although TCP keepalive at HA is probably also warranted.

Comment: Hm I see. So the call to onCompleted on the previous StreamObserver doesn't do anything even when the channel is ready because it's essentially toast? And the server should be responsible for timing out the dead connection? 

I ask because our way of resolving is essentially to fail over our active node which shuts down the managedChannel once, and then shut it down again, which clears both the new connection and the old. It's annoying because that connection still remains "open" on client and server, it just seems like it's unusable.

Comment: On client-side, once your onCompleted/onError is called, the RPC is dead. For the StreamObserver API, you are supposed to call onError/onCompleted on the request-side if you haven't already, but it is more just for the API contract and doesn't hurt anything if not done. If connections are getting "stuck" or "wedged", then keepalive generally improves things substantially. And you need that keepalive on both client-side and server-side because the two sides have to discover the issue independently.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. It seems what was happening is that the ManagedChannel has a default timeout of 30 minutes. I don't know exactly what happens under the hood, but when our keepalive ping (set at an interval of 1 hour) fired, onError was triggered. So our client knows that the bidi RPC must be called again, but the server had no keepalive to know that the connection was torn down. We've circumvented the issue by extending the timeout period and reducing the keepalive interval until the server engineers are ready to implement necessary changes on their end.

Comment: Are you referring to [idle timeout](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ManagedChannelBuilder.html#idleTimeout-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)? That only applies if no RPCs exist on the channel for 30 minutes. That seems unrelated. But the rest of that sounds normal and yes, you should probably enable the built-in keepalive support on both client and server.

Comment: Yes, I can clarify. Initially, we had no keepalive on either side and overnight, we noticed that onError was triggered every 2 hours, prompting us to recall our bidi stream API. I then tried instantiating a keepalive in the channel every hour, and then onError started getting triggered every hour. Because we have to get this to clients pretty soon for the first release, we put in an application level ping which we have in our protobuf. I feel silly for not just reducing the keepalive time, but we kind of ran out of time for testing. For the next iteration I'll look into using the ServiceConfig