# gRPC server received 'client cancelled' but client didn't receive an error

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

Extending on my conversation with Eric A. [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71851301/grpc-client-side-reconnection-logic-causing-duplicate-streams-to-be-opened-serve), I've seen instances in which the client side gets onError called on its StreamObserver, but the server doesn't and vice versa. Both client and server are going to include channel level keepalive with a time of 30s intervals. I've set my channel's timeout to 10s.

What I want to be sure of, however, is that when the server side gets onError called on its StreamObserver for any reason, would the keepalive capture this? What if server gets an error and recovers quickly, calls onError on their previous StreamObserver, and the client sends a message on the stream? Would this bounce back an error to the client?

The reason I ask is because a couple days ago we saw an NPE on server side because instead of calling onError on their StreamObserver, they set it to null, and we tried to send a message on the stream, they got an NPE. This might be further muddled by the fact that server side has three HA nodes, and I'm not particularly keen on all of the details.

Another thing I wanted to ask about that I've seen around SO is the gRPC Context. To detect ANY cancel on the other side of the stream, is it as simple as adding a listener:

```
Context.current.addListener((context) -> {
    log.info("Other side received cancel with cause '{}', context.cancellationCause.toString());
    
    // can't use our StreamObservers anymore, call onCompleted() on our streams
    // ... insert code here
    
   // Call the bidirection stream RPC on the stubs again to reassign StreamObservers
   // ... insert code here


 };
```

The Javadocs about the Context confused me a little bit. If other side gets an error for ANY reason and has to recover by reassigning their StreamObserver after calling onComplete or onError on it, does the OTHER side need to know and do the same?